# NSTask string syntax problems

Tags: macos, swift

I am trying to run the following terminal command on a button press in my swift app but can't seem to figure out the String syntax.

```
peerflix "magentlinkhere" --vlc
```

I want magnetlinkhere and --vlc to be variables I can feed into the NSTask.

The function I currently have is this:

```
var videoPlayer = "vlc"
var torrentS = "magnetlinkhere"

func openVideo() {
    let openApp = NSTask()
    openV.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
    openV.arguments = ["peerflix "\("torrentS.stringValue")\" --"\(videoPlyer)"]
    openV.launch()
}
```

This code should execute the following in terminal

```
peerflix "magnetlinkhere" --vlc
```

Could anyone help me with the formatting here? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

First, when you pass a whole command string to `bash` (or, more typically, `sh`), you need to use the `-c` option. The command string is actually part of the `-c` option, not an argument as such. So, that should be the first element of your arguments array.

As far as the quoting goes, you can try this:

```
openApp.arguments = ["-c", "peerflix \"\(torrentS)\" --\(videoPlayer)"]
```

However, this is dangerous. The shell will interpret the command string you pass. If it has characters that the shell considers special, it may do various things, including running commands. Putting quotes around the first argument isn't really enough. For one thing, if either of your variables includes quote marks, that will interfere with the quoting you're trying to do. For another, certain special characters (e.g. `$`) are still interpreted inside quotes.

You can try to improve the quoting and do a bit of backslash-escaping to try to make the string safe against shell interpretation. However, the safer option is to just skip the shell and execute the program directly and supply its arguments.

For example:

```
let task = NSTask()
task.launchPath = "peerflix" // actually need the absolute path here
task.arguments = [torrentS, "--\(videoPlayer)"]
task.launch()
```

The only complication there is that you actually need to supply the absolute path to the `peerflix` executable. You can't rely on it being on the `PATH` or on `NSTask` finding it there. (Frankly, you can't rely on it being installed at all. So, I assume you must be shipping it with your app or something. In that case, you should get the path by looking it up in your bundle.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, unfortunately when I use the second one, I get `env: node: No such file or directory` even though I am specifying the absolute path (I think) `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/peerflix/app.js`

Comment: You're presumably not entering the path to that `app.js` file in a shell. If you're able to run `peerflix` in a shell, then type `which peerflix` to find out the absolute path to what it's running. Using that in your app may still not work because it seems to be depending on the `node` command being found on the `PATH`, but GUI apps don't get the same `PATH` as an interactive shell uses. You may need to add the relevant directories to the `PATH` inherited by the task by setting its `environment` property.

Comment: However, if you're trying to write an app to ship to others, it can't depend on things like Node.js or peerflix being installed in /usr/local, etc. It has to ship them.